# How to fix 412 (Precondition Failed) Error HTML5 Video Tag

Tags: html5-video, preconditions, http-status-code-412

I am using HTML5 video tag inside FlexSlider. Sometimes video stops working. After lot of search I got this error.

```
GET http://studiobooth.local/app/videos/0062mParticle12151601.mp4 412 (Precondition Failed)
```

Here is my HTML5 Video tag code:

```
<video preload="none" src="http://studiobooth.local/app/videos/2.mp4" poster="http://studiobooth.local/app/videos/thumbs/2.jpg" controls="" loop="" style="max-width:100%;height:100%;"><source src="http://studiobooth.local/app/videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

Please help me to fix it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a temporary solution which helped me to make it working. Here is my code in which I am appending milli-seconds to the file source url and re-loading the same video file if any error occurred.

```
media.addEventListener('error', function (e) {

   var date = new Date();
   var milliSecs = date.getMilliseconds();
   var curr_src = $(media[0]).attr('src');
   var curr_src_arr = curr_src.split("?");
   var new_src = curr_src_arr[0]+"?t="+milliSecs;

   $(media[0]).attr('src',new_src);
   $(media[0]).find('source').attr('src',new_src);
   media[0].load();
   //media[0].play(); /* Here we can not trigger play video/audio without user interaction. */
}, false);
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW1